Unable to read Group Members info (msgraph)
I’ve granted my app registration Group.ReadAll and GroupMember.ReadAll permissions. However, without Directory.ReadAll, I’m only able to retrieve member IDs, not detailed information like displayName or UPN.
App Perm: https://i.imgur.com/ensbfCo.png
Could someone clarify or confirm if Directory.ReadAll is absolutely required for accessing this information?
from azure.identity import UsernamePasswordCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient
import json

# Azure AD App Registration and user details
# Only delegated type permission provided
# Enabled public client flows
client_id = 'xxxxxxxx-exx0-xx75-xxxx-9834a4xxxxxx'
username = 'username@xxxx.com'
password = 'password'  # UserCredFlow
tenant_id = 'xxxxxx21-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-8ed26bxxxxxx'

# Group details
group_name = "GroupName"
group_id = 'GroupID'

def get_group_members(client, group_id):
    members = []
    next_link = f'/groups/{group_id}/members?$select=id,displayName,userPrincipalName'
    
    while next_link:
        result = client.get(next_link)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            data = result.json()
            members.extend(data.get('value', []))
            next_link = data.get('@odata.nextLink')
        else:
            print(f"Error: {result.status_code}", result.text)
            break
    
    return members

try:
    credential = UsernamePasswordCredential(client_id=client_id, username=username, 
                                            password=password, tenant_id=tenant_id)
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)

    # Verify connection
    me_result = client.get('/me')
    if me_result.status_code == 200:
        print("Successfully connected as:", me_result.json().get('userPrincipalName', 'Unknown User'))
    else:
        print(f"Failed to connect. Error: {me_result.status_code}", me_result.text)
        exit(1)

    # Get and print group members
    print(f"\nRetrieving members of group: {group_name}")
    members = get_group_members(client, group_id)

    print(f"\nTotal number of members in the group: {len(members)}")
    print("Group Members:")

    for i, member in enumerate(members, 1):
        print(f"\nMember {i}:")
        print(f"ID: {member.get('id', 'N/A')}")
        print(f"Display Name: {member.get('displayName', 'N/A')}")
        print(f"User Principal Name: {member.get('userPrincipalName', 'N/A')}")

    # Print available fields for the first member
    if members:
        print("\nAvailable fields for each member:")
        print(", ".join(members[0].keys()))

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Yj6g7FWx.png


Can you please share your  API Permission blade?

Hi @PratikJadhav updated my question with the screenshot

GroupMember.Read.All gives basics information of member of the group MsDoc GroupMember.Read.All and Directory.Read.All gives complete information of the members of groupMsDocs Directory.Read.All

To read the basic properties of a group's members that are users, you need either the delegated permission User.ReadBasic.All or User.Read.All.
To read the basic properties of a group's members that are groups, you need at least the Group.Read.All permission.
In general, you need a permission to read a certain resource type.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http#limited-information-returned-for-inaccessible-member-objects
